# how to upload mp3 files to github and play them from a webbrowser

Tags: reactjs, github, audio

I created a repository and then I uploaded audio files into it.
When I go to the audio files, for example: https://github.com/cre8ture/audioFilesForBL/blob/main/1.mp3

It goes to the github page, rather than playing the audio file directly.

My ultimate aim is to upload a few audio files so that a website using React can play the audio file

for instance I'd like to load

```
const audioTune = new Audio("https://github.com/cre8ture/audioFilesForBL/blob/main/1.mp3");
```

and play that file.

Thank you

Comment: To serve files from github you probably want to look at [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/)

Comment: You need to link to the "raw" file (the link on the Download button). In this case it would be: https://github.com/cre8ture/audioFilesForBL/raw/main/1.mp3 Also Github is not really meant to be used to host files in this way.

Comment: Thanks @Double_A! do you know a better free service to host about 20 mb where i can pull into a website?

Answer (score 2):

I"m sure you already figured it out but append the url with "**?raw=true**" and it should run.

so like:
**"https://github.com/cre8ture/audioFilesForBL/blob/main/1.mp3?raw=true"**

Comment: in my case it'll download the file instead of playing it